# text input (input type="text") value is not updating after changing property using an event with LitElement library

Tags: javascript, lit

The source code:

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from '../vendor/lit-2.4.0/lit-all.min.js';

export class SearchInput extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            src: { type: String },
            items: { type: Array }
        }
    };

    static styles = css`
    `;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.items = [
            { text: 'Hola' },
            { text: 'mundo!' }
        ];
        this.selectedItem = null;
        this.text = 'foo';
    }

    selectItem(item) {
        this.selectedItem = item;
        this.text = this.selectedItem.text;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" value="${this.text}">
                <ul class="result-list">
                    ${this.items.map((item) => html`<li @click="${this.selectItem(item)}">${item.text}</li>`)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}
customElements.define('search-input', SearchInput);
```

The text input (input type="text") value is not updating after changing property (`this.text`) using an event (`this.selectItem`) with LitElement library.

I tried it in browser but there is no error in browser console.
I expect that input value update after changing property with the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the question! There are a few minor issues resulting in the value not updating.

One issue is that `this.text` is not a [reactive property](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/), so changing it isn't scheduling a re-render. Fix is to add `text` to the static properties.

The second issue is that your event listener click handler is the result of calling `this.selectItems(item)` and not a function, fixed with: `@click=${() => this.selectItems(item)}`.

Bonus: You may want to change the value attribute expression to a [property expression](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions) using the [live directive](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live), `.value="${live(this.text)}"`. I suggested this because the native `input` browser element always updates its contents if you update the `value` property, but only updates before a user has interacted with it when updating the `value` attribute. And the `live` directive is useful to tell Lit to dirty check the live DOM value in the `input` element.

Your code with the minor fixes: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=a23dfbcdfbfcfb7de28b1f7255aaa8ee

or running in StackOverflow:

```html
<script type="module">
import { LitElement, html, live } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/all/lit-all.min.js';

class SearchInput extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      src: { type: String },
      items: { type: Array },
      text: { type: String }, // <- Added this to make `this.text` a reactive property.
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.items = [
      { text: 'Hola' },
      { text: 'mundo!' },
      { text: 'click these' },
    ];
    this.selectedItem = null;
    this.text = 'foo';
  }

  selectItem(item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    this.text = this.selectedItem.text;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div class="control">
        <!-- live directive is needed because user can edit the value of the input.
              This tells Lit to dirty check against the live DOM value. -->
        <input class="input" type="text" .value="${live(this.text)}">
        <ul class="result-list">
            <!-- Click event is a function -->
            ${this.items.map((item) =>
              html`<li @click="${() => this.selectItem(item)}">${item.text}</li>`)}
        </ul>
      </div>
      `;
  }
}
customElements.define('search-input', SearchInput);
</script>
<search-input></search-input>
```

Comment: If you are using the npm packages the live function is in a directive `import { live } from 'lit/directives/live.js'`